# Open file in Tcl with variables inside

Tags: shell, scripting, tcl, tclsh

I want to open a file called `filelist.txt` which contains only the string `${PATHFILE}/test.txt`, read the line and open the file `test.txt`. The file `test.txt` is present inside the folder `~/testfile`.
Consider this sample code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

set PATHFILE "~/testfile"

set fp [open "filelist.txt" r]
set lines [split [read $fp] "\n"]
close $fp   

foreach line $lines {
    set fp1 [open $line r]
    close $fp1
}
```

The problem is that it seems that the "open" command cannot find the `PATHFILE` variable and i get this error:

```
couldn't open "${PATHFILE}/test.txt": no such file or directory
```

If i try to open the file with `set fp1 [open "${PATHFILE}/test.txt" r]` i don't have any errors.

Comment: possibly the *subst* command https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/subst would help?

Comment: Thank you, by using `set fp1 [open [subst $line] r]` i was able to solve the issue!

Comment: Tcl _never_ substitutes anything in a string except when told to.

Comment: Is every file path in `filelist.txt` rooted in `$PATHFILE`? If yes, why maintain variable references in `filelist.txt` in the first place? Better assemble the complete file path in your script, by calling `file join $PATHFILE $line` ... and make `filelist.txt` contain only `test.txt\ntest2.txt\ntest3.txt` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [TCL subst command](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/subst.htm) to evaluate the PATHFILE variable. Note that you might still have an issue with the tilde ~ - it may be better to use full path names.

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

set PATHFILE "~/testfile"

set fp [open "filelist.txt" r]
set lines [split [read $fp] "\n"]
close $fp   

foreach line $lines {
    set fp1 [open [subst $line] r]
    close $fp1
}
```

Comment: to protect yourself from some malicious-ness, use `subst -nocommands -nobackslashes $line` -- see https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/subst.htm

Comment: One may consider applying `subst` once to the entire content of the opened file (`split [subst -nocommands -nobackslashes [read $fp]] \n`), then process each line.